# jquery.min.js 'no such interface supported'

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I am using this multipush menu ....

http://multi-level-push-menu.make.rs/

it works great with all browsers and all versions except i.e9 ... I dont know why but f12 is saying that when i click on the menu button to open the sidebar it throws this error...

```
 SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'defaultView': object is null or undefined 
jquery.min.js, line 3 character 18072
```

this is the code that is highlighted ...

```
{return b.ownerDocument.defaultView.opener?b.ownerDocument.defaultView.getComputedStyle(b,null):a.getComputedStyle(b,null)}
```

any ideas why i.e 9 doesn't like this bit of jquery code ?

EDIT - Bypassing this completely and writing a function to accommodate the three classes that would of normally been moved as the menu opens/closed... so

I know that this is recognized by i.e9 for the open and close true/false

```
$('#menu').multilevelpushmenu({Collapsed: true});
```

so i need an if stament contained within my current i.e9 only applicable code that says if its true then move the classes 330 from the left  this is what i have so far....

```
if ( ms_ie ) {
        $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu({Collapsed: true});
        $( ".navbtn, .submenu-ctn, .logo-title" ).animate({
        left: "-=330",
        }, 500); 
        }else{
      $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('collapse');
      }
```

and this works, what i need is perhaps another one to say generally if collapsed = false the move everything +300 , ... nearly there

Comment: When posting minimized code, please take the time to identify what character 3694 is.

Comment: It *might* be relating to: `x.support.boxSizingReliable||i===e.style[t]`

Comment: ok i made some changes and now this is the remaining issue and is specific

Comment: Can you make a minimal case that blows up in IE9?

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: it is version 2.1.4 although i have tried version 1 different types but same result

Comment: Well, post your code up so we can have a look. Hard to troubleshoot without knowing what is exactly going on.

Comment: i am working on a solution that bypasses the error and does some simple javascript , bare with me I will post soon

Comment: editing what ive got so far